# How to append data to a series in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a chart I want to update as data comes in from an `mqtt` channel.  However, I don't see how to append the `steps` series on the correct message.

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#epoch-report',
    data: {
     columns: [
       ['steps',]
     ]
   },
   axis:{
      x: {
        max: .1,
        label: {
          text: "Epoch"
        }
      },
      y: {
        max: .1,
        label: {
          text: "Step",
        }
      }
   }
  });
  if (topic == "/epoch/update") {
    var j = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(payload));
    var msg = "<br> Epoch: " + j.id + " steps: " + j.steps + " winner: " + j.winner;
    document.getElementById('epoch-report').innerHTML += msg;
    console.log("Now I want to add data to ");
    console.log(chart.data.values);
  } else if (topic == "/epoch/setup") {
    var j = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(payload));
    console.log("setting up epoch dash with max steps " + j.maxsteps);
  }
```

I do not seem to be able to access `chart.data.columns['step']` or anything similar. How do I add to `steps`?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle/codepen with some test data?